# Como acumular la cantidad de visitas a una determinada url en django?

Tags: javascript, html, python, django

resulta que quisiera guardar en la propiedad de un objeto la cantidad de visitas que se genera en determinadas urls.

Para aclarar, estoy haciendo una app donde agregue proyectos y dentro de ese proyecto su contenido. Entonces me gustaria que cada vez que se ingrese a un determinado proyecto, se le acumule en el campo visitas.

En la url del contenido de cada proyecto esta su pk, entonces pense ir por ese lado pero no se me ocurre.

Tambien intente usar `request.session.get('visits')` e ir acumulando pero esto es global, no por cada proyecto separados.

Desde ya, muchas gracias!
Si necesitan algun codigo o algo, lo actualizo o lo envio en una respuesta!!

Answer (score 0):

Lo que fallaba y no me daba cuenta era el uso del get(), en ves de filter() en la busqueda de un projecto(objeto) en especifico.

Por lo que solucionando esto, el codigo me quedo algo asi:

project_visits = Projects.objects.filter(id=pk)

project_visits.update(visits=F('visits') + 1)

Comment: Bienvenido. Esto no es un foro, ests publicación está en la zona de respuestas así que, ¿Cómo lo arreglaste entonces?

Comment: Hola! Añado una respuesta con la solucion?

Comment: Sí, edita esta publicación.